# Problems with Bool Tools difference

Tags: modifiers

I am having issues regarding the Bool Tool stuff, more specifically the Auto Boolean difference tool. Whenever I attempt to use the tool between two objects, it gives me a Traceback error. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

I am somewhat new to Blender, and I had to install Bool Tools manually (it did not appear in the user settings menu).

Answer (score 1):

I found out my problem. The Bool Tool Blender Wiki article has the wrong link. Go to the Github dl here: https://www.blendernation.com/2014/05/14/add-on-booltool/
Then download the .rar
Optionally, after downloading the .rar move to whatever folder you want.
Open with 7zip or a program that can open .rar files, and move the BoolTools.py into the folder.
Open Blender, go to User Preferences, addons, and install from file. Go to where you have BoolTools.py and select that to be installed from file. Enable it by checking the black box on the side. That should work for you, as it worked from me.

Sorry for my stupidity, I am rather new to Blender.